# Unlock or delete locked folder programmatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, file-management, file-unlocking

### 1. Summary

I'm couldn't find, how I can unlock or delete locked folder with all subfolders via command-line interface.

---

### 2. Argumentation

I'm working on the project. For example, my sources folder — `sources`, output folder — `output`. I view files and/or make test changes in `output` → I add changes to `sources` → I run build command (`build`, for example), which should overwrite `output`. But `build` doesn't start correctly:

[image: Folder In Use]

> Folder In Use
>
> The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program
>
> Close the folder or file and try again

Therefore, before each `build` starting I opened LockHunter → unlocked `output` → ran `build`.

It would be nice, if would be possible run command for unlocking or deleting `output` before `build`, that I don't need manually run LockHunter every time, spending time on it.

---

### 3. MCVE

I created a folder `KiraUnlockCLI` → opened command prompt → moved to `KiraUnlockCLI` in it (`cd KiraUnlockCLI`) → `KiraUnlockCLI` locked:

[image: Folder locked]

I need unlock or delete `KiraUnlockCLI` programmatically.

---

### 4. Requirements

1. Any type of program can lock `output` folder and/or files in it, examples:

   1. Windows Explorer
   2. Command prompt
   3. Text editor
   4. Browser
   5. Images viewer
2. Solution must unlock folders, not files solely. I can open in third-party programs any files in `output` and its subfolders.
3. Relative paths must be supported. `output` is located in different directories for me, another developers and Continuous Integration (Travis CI, AppVeyor).

---

### 5. Not helped

#### 5.1. Relative paths

1. [**LockHunter**](https://lockhunter.com/) doesn't support relative paths.

   At the beginning of September 2019 I [**wrote an issue**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaMiscellaneous/issues/29) → I told about my issue in [**LockHunter Feedback form**](https://lockhunter.com/support.htm) → I haven't received any feedback.

#### 5.2. Folders support

These programs can unlock files, not folders.

1. [**FileASSASSIN**](https://www.malwarebytes.com/fileassassin/):

   ```
   FileASSASSIN /unlock /silent KiraUnlockCLI
   ```
2. [**BusyDelete**](http://www.burtonsys.com/freezerware_backup/software/console.shtml)

#### 5.3. Specific PID

1. [**Handle**](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/handle) — PIDs required for unlocking. But I need kill processes with any PID; see 4.1 item of my question.

#### 5.4. GUI

I couldn't find any information about command-line interface of these programs:

1. [**IObit Unlocker**](https://www.iobit.com/en/iobit-unlocker.php)
2. [**Unlock IT**](https://emcosoftware.com/unlock-i)

#### 5.5. Doesn't work

1. `rm -rf KiraUnlockCLI` (`rm` from [**GnuWin32**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/getgnuwin32/)):

   ```
   /usr/bin/rm: cannot remove 'KiraUnlockCLI`: Device or resource busy
   ```
2. [**OpenedFilesView**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html) — no effect after this command:

   ```
   openedfilesview /closefolder closeprocess killprocess KiraUnlockCLI
   ```
3. [**WhoLockMe**](http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/) [**doesn't work in Windows 10**](https://superuser.com/a/117908/572069).
4. [**Unlocker**](http://emptyloop.com/unlocker/) — `unlocker D:\SashaDebugging\KiraUnlockCLI`:

   [image: Unlocker]

   > No Locking handle found.
   >
   > However Unlocker can help you deal with this object.
   >
   > Choose the action you want to perform on the object.
5. [**DeadLock**](https://codedead.com/?page_id=822) can't unlock folders via command-line interface. See [**my issue**](https://github.com/CodeDead/DeadLock/issues/12) to DeadLock issue tracker.

---

### 6. Don't offer

1. I'm know [**side effects**](https://superuser.com/a/728306/572069); please, don't tell me, that I don't need unlock folder.
2. I read these SuperUser questions and answers to them before post my question:

   1. [**Can't delete empty folder because it is used**](https://superuser.com/q/1333118/572069)
   2. [**Is there a way to handle locked file from command line and release it?**](https://superuser.com/q/426602/572069)
   3. [**How do I delete a folder that's in use?**](https://superuser.com/q/2937/572069)
   4. [**Delete a directory from the Windows command line even if it's been opened in a program**](https://superuser.com/q/1341215/572069)
   5. [**Delete locked file/folder from command line**](https://superuser.com/q/366977/572069)
3. I checked programs from [**this list**](http://emptyloop.com/unlocker/#comparison) on the Unlocker site.

Answer (score 1):

Ever since I've found IOBit Unlocker (~10 years ago) I stopped using all of the ones you supplied and a few others, why? it actually deletes the files/folders no matter what, has clean interface and also you can automate (as you asked). A few years later I've come across an online article stating that it even deletes Avast AV files that are potected and in use.

If you want, you can install and leave it like that or simply get the files and use it standalone (use `IObitUnlocker.exe /?` to see command line help):

Installed:

```
IObitUnlocker.exe /Delete /Advanced <folder>
```

Standalone:

```
cd <app folder>
sc create IObitUnlocker type= kernel start= demand binPath= "IObitUnlocker.sys"
IObitUnlocker.exe /Delete /Advanced <folder>
sc delete IObitUnlocker
rd /S /Q %AllUsersProfile%\IObit
```

An automation-wise downside is that displays a message after the action, but you can use `timeout /T <time> && taskkill /IM IObitUnlocker.exe`. The `<time>` depends on folder contents/hierarchy, how many files are in use, the speed of your system and the CPU/HDD load). Bear in mind that elevation is needed for unlocking.

If you happen to use AutoHotKey the dialog dismissing (and whatever UI interaction you could think of) is trivially easy to automate.

```
SetTimer, DismissUnlocker, 1000
DismissUnlocker() {
  If WinExist("IObit Unlocker ahk_class #32770")
    ControlClick, Button1
}
```